# Create a custom block in org-mode that exports to latex and html

Tags: org-mode

I'm writing a long research org-mode document that I want to export to both LaTeX, ODT and HTML. The most important export environment is to LaTeX.

I would like to be able to specify an environment inside the org-mode document without specifying the language. For instance, I could write:

```
#+latex: \begin{acknowledgement}
...
#+latex: \end{acknowledgement}
```

But I would prefer to write something like:

```
#+begin_acknowledgement
..
#+end_acknowledgement
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Org is very customizable, [special blocks](http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-blocks.html) allow the syntax you want.  [this page](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2013/11/30/Custom-directives/) has an example of customizing the html syntax for a block, but for latex you may need to [modify the exporter](http://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-configuration.html) by adding a special-block-filter.  I'm putting this as a comment since it's not a complete solution.

Comment: yes, I can see the special blocks are now in the core of the org-mode. But it has to be loaded as a module in `org-modules`. I got it to work by reloading the org-mode afterward. It was almost a complete solution for me :)